# How to add arrows in the middle of the Plot-lines

Tags: plotting

If I got a bunch of numbers,then I can plot it with `ListPlot`:

```
{{1, 2}, {3, 9}, {7, 4}, {9, 9}}

 ListPlot[%, Joined -> True]
```

Then I get

[image]

Now I would like to have arrows in the middle of these lines, like this:
[image]

Or maybe not in this way, but we got arrows in the end of each lines.

That's OK too.

If there is thousands of numbers like that, is there a simple way to add arrows like this?

Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 15):

```
dt = {{1, 2}, {3, 9}, {7, 4}, {9, 9}};

Graphics[Arrow /@ Partition[dt, 2, 1], Frame -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{Line @ dt, Arrow /@ Partition[dt, 2, 1] /. 
  {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> {{a, b}, {(a + c)/2, (b + d)/2}}}, 
    Frame -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**Edit** thanks to @J.M.

The above result (arrowheads in the middle) can be obtained more easily with

```
Graphics[{Arrowheads[{{.05, 0.5}}], Arrow /@ Partition[dt, 2, 1]},Frame -> Automatic]
```

Comment: You can use an `Arrowheads[]` specification to position the arrowheads in the middle of the segments.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an interactive way you could place arrowheads,e.g second row could be copied and pasted into function once desired placement was achieved.

```
lst = {{1, 2}, {3, 9}, {7, 4}, {9, 9}};
Manipulate[
 Column[{ListPlot[lst, Joined -> True] /. 
    Line[x__] :> {Arrowheads[ {{ah, ahp1}, {ah, ahp2}, {ah, ahp3}}], 
      Arrow[x]},
   {{ah, ahp1}, {ah, ahp2}, {ah, ahp3}}
   }]
 , {ah, 0.05, 0.2}, {ahp1, 0, 1}, {ahp2, 0, 1}, {ahp3, 0, 1}]
```

[image]