# Creating a custom ListPlot of consecutive points

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

Here comes some sample data

```
data = {{0, 0.7, 0.4}, {1, 0.831177, 0.51854}, {2, 1.11106, 0.463533}, 
        {3, 1.84226, -0.642571}, {4, 0.677049, -0.327877}, 
        {5, 0.77886, -0.451322}, {6, 0.965874, -0.508772}, 
        {7, 1.34397, -0.202473}, {8, 1.01761, -0.717013}, 
        {9, -0.0507992, -1.3864}, {10, -0.102145, -0.957957}, 
        {11, -0.00228078, -0.861489}}
```

The first integer is a counter, while the other two reals are the $(x,y)$ coordinates.

Let's plot these points

```
d0 = data[[All, {2, 3}]];
L0 = ListPlot[d0, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, 
     PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.002], PointSize[0.012]}, 
     Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 500]
```

Now I want the customize the plot as follows:

(a). Add arrows showing the evolution of the points, like

[image]

(b). The first point with counter 0 should be plotted in red, while the last point should be plotted in blue.

(c). Add labels near to the points indicating the corresponding counter (e.g, 2, 3, etc). The label of the first point should be $P_0$, instead of 0, while for the last point the label should be $P_f$.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Graph` with directed edges

```
labels = Thread[
   Range[12] -> (Placed[#, Above] & /@ 
      Join[{Subscript[x, 0]}, Range[10], {Subscript[x, f]}])];
Graph[# \[DirectedEdge] # + 1 & /@ Range[11], VertexCoordinates -> d0,
  VertexLabels -> labels, VertexStyle -> {1 -> Red, 12 -> Blue}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or, if you need to have it look like the plot above,

```
labels = Thread[
   Range[12] -> (Placed[#, Above] & /@ 
      Join[{Subscript["x", 0]}, Range[10], {Subscript["x", "f"]}])];
labels = MapAt[Style[#, 15, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"] &, 
   labels, {All, 2, 1}];
Show[
 Graph[# \[DirectedEdge] # + 1 & /@ Range[11], 
  VertexCoordinates -> d0, VertexLabels -> labels, 
  VertexStyle -> {1 -> Red, 12 -> Blue}],
 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 500, 
 PlotRangePadding -> .1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice work! a couple of issues: (a). the labels should be just 2,3,4,... not P_2, P_3, ..., (b). The last point should be blue and (c) the label of the first point should be $P_0$ instead of $P_f$.

Comment: So the labels should go as `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}`?

Comment: The labels should be {x_0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, x_f}.

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks :)

Comment: In Mathematica v9 I cannot reproduce the second plot. The code is not being evaluated.

Comment: Forgot to format it as code, so the escape character didn't come through.  Should work now

Comment: Yes, now it's working fine! x_0 and x_f look like they have italic font. Can this be changed? Also is there a way to change the color of the arrows  connecting the points?

Comment: I think you can just replace `Subscript[x, 0]` with `Subscript["x", 0]`

Comment: A final query: how can I change the size and the fonts of the labels?

Comment: By using a `Style` in the right place :-)

Comment: Many thanks once more!

Answer (score 3):

```
r3 = AppendTo[Table[{Graphics[{Text[
     Which[i == 1, Subscript[P, 0], i == Length[d0], Subscript[P, f],
    True, ToString[i - 1]], Offset[{0, 10}, d0[[i]]]]}], 
    Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Which[i == 1, Red], 
   Which[i == Length[d0] - 1, {Point[d0[[i]]], Blue, 
   Point[d0[[i + 1]]]}, True, Point[d0[[i]]]]}], 
   Graphics[{Arrow[d0[[i ;; i + 1]]]}], 
   Graphics[{White, Point[{0.5, 0.6}]}]}, {i, 1, Length[d0] - 1}], 
   Graphics[{Text[Subscript[P, f], Offset[{0, 10}, Last@d0]]}]]


 Show[r3, Frame -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, but the last arrow after $P_f$ is not needed!

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z - I think the issue there is that the last point is omitted, since the table is iterated over `{i, 1, Length[d0] - 1}` the last point gets missed.  A similar effect is had [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97814/9490) but without the labeling concerns

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z  Edited