# Join data point with arrows in ErrorListPlot

Tags: plotting

the data is

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];

data={{{{-1.04845, -1.16241}, ErrorBar[0.0001]}, {{-1.06996, -1.16277}, 
   ErrorBar[0.00006]}, {{-1.00061, -1.16337}, 
   ErrorBar[0.00006]}, {{-1.19685, -1.16283}, 
   ErrorBar[0.00008]}, {{-1.1696, -1.16354}, 
   ErrorBar[0.00005]}, {{-1.01451, -1.16399}, 
   ErrorBar[0.00006]}}, {{{-0.49151, -1.16241}, 
   ErrorBar[0.0001]}, {{-0.45521, -1.16277}, 
   ErrorBar[0.00006]}, {{-0.39356, -1.16337}, 
   ErrorBar[0.00006]}, {{-0.39785, -1.16283}, 
   ErrorBar[0.00008]}, {{-0.35805, -1.16354}, 
   ErrorBar[0.00005]}, {{-0.34185, -1.16399}, ErrorBar[0.00006]}}}
```

And I plot it with

```
ErrorListPlot[data,
  Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic}, Joined -> True, 
 Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All]
```

which gives

[image]

I want to add arrow **in the middle** of each line of this plot to show the evolution of data like below

[image]

**What is the best way to do this?**

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60838/adding-arrows-in-curves and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97813/how-to-add-arrows-in-the-middle-of-the-plot-lines

Comment: @march Hi, march. Sorry for my mistake. Thank you for correcting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually modify plots using the following methods. It's rarely automated, but it works.  The plan is to replace the `Line`s in the `Graphics` object represented by the figure with `Arrow`s, but we need to find them first.

First, we use the data in the OP and name the function `plt`:

```
plt = ErrorListPlot[data,
       Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic},
       Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All];
```

Then, we want to extract from the plot all `Graphics` primitives that are `Line`s using

```
Cases[Normal[plt], _Line, Infinity]
```

The first three elements of this list are

```
{Line[{{-1.04845, -1.16241}, {-1.06996, -1.16277}, {-1.00061, -1.16337}, {-1.19685, -1.16283}, {-1.1696, -1.16354}, {-1.01451, -1.16399}}],
 Line[{{-1.04845, -1.16231}, {-1.04845, -1.16251}}], 
 Line[{Offset[{1.5, 0}, {-1.04845, -1.16231}],
 ... }
```

The first element is the `Line` joining the points (and there is another one later on). The second element is the vertical error bar, and the third is one of either the top or lower horizontal bars in the error bar. We only want to extract the `Line`s joining the points, so we do

```
Cases[Normal[plt], Line[a_?(FreeQ[#, Offset] &)] /; Length[a] > 2, Infinity]
(* {Line[{{-1.04845, -1.16241}, {-1.06996, -1.16277}, {-1.00061, -1.16337}, {-1.19685, -1.16283}, {-1.1696, -1.16354}, {-1.01451, -1.16399}}],
    Line[{{-0.49151, -1.16241}, {-0.45521, -1.16277}, {-0.39356, -1.16337}, {-0.39785, -1.16283}, {-0.35805, -1.16354}, {-0.34185, -1.16399}}]} *)
```

That's them! So we modify the plot as follows:

```
plt
  /. Line[a_?(FreeQ[#, Offset] &)] /; Length[a] > 2
      :> {Arrowheads[{{0.05, 0.5}}], Arrow /@ Partition[a, 2, 1]}
```

resulting in

[image]

Comment: Hi, march. Thank you very much for your answer. I learned a lot of clever tricks from your answer. One thing I don't understand is `Normal`. I never thought `Normal` could apply to a plot ! It seems that this is not documented and I still haven't figured out what exactly has `Normal` done to a plot. for example, I found `Cases[plt, Line[a_?(FreeQ[#, Offset] &)] /; Length[a] > 2, Infinity]` only got `{Line[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}], Line[{7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}]}`

Comment: @matheorem, `Normal[]` converts `GraphicsComplex[]` objects (which are usually produced by plotting functions) into an explicit list of primitives and directives. You can search the site for many examples of its use.

Comment: @J.M. Hi, J.M. That is still not clear. Why `Normal[plt]` deletes the errorbar?

Comment: You can answer that yourself, @matheorem. Ponder on the result of `FreeQ[ErrorListPlot[(* stuff *)], _ErrorBar]`.

Comment: @J.M. Nope. The `plt` is free from `ErrorBar` head already, the errorbar is drawn by `Line`. What I mean is that why `Normal[plt]` output a plot without a errorbar line? You said "Normal[] converts GraphicsComplex[] objects", but you didn't mean it will change the plot, right?

Comment: That seems to be a bug in either `Normal[]` or `GraphicsComplex[]`; the `Line[]`s with `Offset[]` coordinates get removed for some reason. Here is a simpler example: `GraphicsComplex[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}, {Line[{1, 2}], Line[{Offset[{0, -10}, {0, 0}], Offset[{0, 10}, {0, 0}]}]}] // Normal`.

Comment: @J.M. I now got a little confused with answer of march. Have you notice `Cases[Normal@plt, 
 Line[a_?(FreeQ[#, Offset] &)] /; Length[a] > 2, Infinity]` and `Cases[plt, 
 Line[a_?(FreeQ[#, Offset] &)] /; Length[a] > 2, Infinity]` produce different result. As I said before, the latter gives `{Line[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}], Line[{7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}]}` which is not the right line data we want. But `plt/. Line[a_?(FreeQ[#, Offset] &)] /; Length[a] > 2 :> {Arrowheads[{{0.05, 0.5}}],  Arrow /@ Partition[a, 2, 1]}` weirdly produces the right plot with arrow? Why? Am I missing something?

Comment: @matheorem. As for your last question, it seems like `ReplaceAll` automatically "`Normal`izes" the plot so that it can match the patterns correctly. This seems like a good choice for the implementation of `ReplaceAll`, since `GraphicsComplex`es are hard to parse.

Comment: @march Hi, march. Interesting behavior of `ReplaceAll`. But as J.M has pointed out there seems to be a bug in either Normal[] or GraphicsComplex[] cause the removal of `Offset[]`. As I understand it, your code seems relying on the bug removal of `Offset[]`, am I right?

Comment: @matheorem. I'm not really sure, actually. With these kinds of things, I usually just inspect things, try various patterns, and extract things until they work. It's very much trial and error.

Comment: @march I see. Yeah, trial and error, daily experiences : )

Answer (score 4):

```
llp = ListLinePlot[data[[All, All, 1]], Frame -> True, 
    PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[{0, .025, 0}], PlotRange -> All] /.
   Line[x_] :> (Arrow@Partition[x, 2, 1]);

elp = ErrorListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic}, Joined -> False];

Show[llp, elp]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh, using `Show`! Clever trick. Upvoted : )

Comment: I never thought `Arrowheads` could be put into `PlotStyle`, it is undocumented, right?

Comment: @matheorem, thank you for the vote.  Since `Arrowheads` is a graphics _directive_, it can be used in `PlotStyle`. There is an example in the documentation: [Arrow >> Properties  & Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Arrow.html)

Comment: Thank you, kglr. It is just too many things can put into "Style", I never succeeded in figuring them out clearly. : )